# Can you help identify this evergreen shrub?

Tags: identification, shrubs

Can you identify this shrub?

The hedge is trimmed to ~5' tall and the leaves are dark green, glossy with several sharp points on them - except the leaves towards the ends of the branches, they only have a sharp point at the end of the leaf.

We're wanting to plant more of these shrubs but have no idea what they are.

[image: shot of the leaves]
[image: close up of leaf]
[image: pic of shrub]

Answer (score 3):

After further research it appears that it might be Nellie Stevens Holly
https://www.plantingtree.com/products/nellie-stevens-holly